# Real case ODE using solve_ivp

Tags: scipy, ode

I'm new to ODEs (Differential equations) and need to model y' = ax

This is the story :
Let's assume that a population increases by 100% per unit of time ( rate = 1)
For example, if at time 1, the population is 1,
at time 2 it will be 2 persons, and at time 3 , there will be 4 persons, at time 4, there will be 8 persons. (Constant increase)

The speed of change of the population is therefore proportional to the quantity of population.

How can I model this using scipy solve_ivp and draw a good line ?
Thank you

This is my try out :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def model(y,t):
    k = 1 # rate  100%
    dydt = k * y
    return dydt

# Initial condition
y0 = 1

#  Interval , max point, number of points
t = np.linspace(1,3,3)

# Solve Diff eq
y = odeint(model,y0,t)

# Draw
plt.plot(t,y)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('y(t) nb persons population')
plt.show()
```

Result is wrong :

[image]

Could you please point me in the right direction ? Thank you

This is my second try out, result is wrong in my opinion, Should I understand another thing about odes ? :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
k = 1.0 ## k is a rate meaning 100%
def f(y,x): ## This function returns derivatives
    return k*y
xs = np.arange(1,4,1) ## I need growth population infos from 1 to the third hour.
yO = 1 ## At the beggining, population is one person
ys = odeint(f,yO,xs)
print(xs)
print(ys)

plt.plot(xs,ys)
plt.plot(xs,ys,'b*')
plt.xlabel('time in hours')
plt.ylabel('population')
plt.title('population grows 100% per hour')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I think It should be solved using geometric series, but I am trying to understand ODES ...for now, I fail.

Here is the link I used :
https://www.epythonguru.com/2020/09/ODE-Growth-model-in-Python.html

Comment: It's not clear to me that SciPy's answer here is wrong. The ODE here is like a bank account with continuously compounding interest. If you have a bank account with 100% interest per year, continuously compounded, you actually have 2.71 times more each year. Similarly, your example goes up by a factor of e every unit of time.

Comment: Right.  The chart is correct, it's just that you're only plotting 3 points.  If you chart it with 300 points instead, you should see a curve.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but, about the charts, SHould I not be supposed to read 2 persons at time 2 and 4 persons at time 3, because the Growing rate is 100%?

Comment: You could do that, that's a geometric series. A geometric series grows by some multiplier at each time step. It is discrete. However, a differential equation is continuous. This equation is continuously growing, and that growth speeds up future growth.

Comment: Another idea would be to pick a `k` value such that the value of this series doubles every time step. The expression `k = ln(j + 1)` gives you the `k` value required to have this ODE increase by a factor of `j` at each time step. This means that if you set `k = 0.6931471805599453` in this ODE, then the value at each time step doubles.

Comment: Thank you, Nick, It works ! Don' know how to find j, but it works.

Comment: @harmoniuscool `j = 1` means 100% increase over each time unit. `j = 0.5` means 50% increase over each time unit, etc.

Comment: You want `y = 2^(t-1)`. But `y'=k*y` gives `y=C*exp(kt)`. To make these two compatible you have to apply logarithm laws `2^(t-1) = 0.5*exp(ln(2)*t)`, that is, `k=ln(2)`.